# Understanding why volatility in diffusion process $(X_t)_{t \in[0,T]}$ is identifiable/known for continuous observations, but the drift is not?

Tags: continuous-data, identifiability, volatility, diffusion

Why is it that when dealing with continuous time observations of a diffusion process $(X_t)_{t \in[0,T]}$, we say that the volatility $\sigma^2$ is "perfectly identifiable" and just usually assume it to be known. I am not quite sure why this is this case, and why is this not the case for the drift function $b$ as well?

This article (https://epge.fgv.br/users/rubens/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/on-the-statistical-estimation-of-diffusion-processes.pdf) mentions in Section 4 something about estimating through the quadratic variation but I am not sure exactly what is meant by this.

Does anyone have some experience in this area and can help me out? Is there an intuitive explanation as to why the volatility (which is the "instantanous variance") is known if we know the entire sample path up to time $T$ but the drift (which is the "instantanous mean") is not?

Edit: I know some stochastic calculus and what the quadratic variation is but working with in statistics is new to me.